Points on a rigid analytic variety and "points" on a formal model
Let $k$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $X$ be a quasi-compact, quasi-separated rigid analytic variety over $k$. We choose a formal model $\mathcal{X}$ of $X$ over $\mathcal{O}_k$.
If I understand correctly, by Raynauld`s theorem, for a finite extension $K/k$ and a morphism of rigid analytic varieties $f:\text{Sp}(K) \to X$, one may find a morphism $\tilde{f}:\text{Spf}(\mathcal{O}_K) \to \mathcal{X}$ (which may not be unique) such that the generic fiver of $\tilde{f}$ is isomorphic to $f$.
Does a similar result hold in the context of scheme theory? Specifically, for a qcqs scheme $\mathcal{S}$ over $\mathcal{O}_k$ and a morphism $\text{Spec}~K \to S_k$, does there exist a morphism $\text{Spec}~ \mathcal{O}_K \to S$?
For example, in cases where a Néron model does not exist, it seems to me that such a morphism might not exist. If this is indeed the case, could someone explain why this difference arises?

No! Consider the point $1/p$ on the affine line. Yes if $X$ is proper, by the valuative criterion. In a way, $p$-adic completion removes all points for which the valuative criterion fails.
